# How to configure Azure DevOps with SQL DB

Tags: azure-devops

We Have Automated scripts that we would like to build and Test on Azure DevOps but our pipeline cannot run our Test Scripts on Azure
We have a Database Service Account that we want to configure on Azure but we don't know how to go about it. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a well explained video (by Hassan Habib from Microsoft) on exactly how to run a console app (you create) in an Azure Pipeline that securely gets credentials to immediately do stuff in Azure (https://youtu.be/ht0xhQyF1x4?t=1688)

He basically, in a handful of minutes shows exactly how to:

1. Link Pipeline Variables to KeyVault Secrets, so when accessed, the variables do a get() from KeyVault and return that value.
2. Securely links Pipeline Variables to Azure Environment Variables.
3. As a step in the release pipeline the console app reads the Azure Environment Variables to get credentials to do stuff in Azure.
4. In his case he created an Azure Resource Group in Azure.

In your case if I’m understanding correctly. You could possibly make a simple console app that runs in the pipeline, that gets creds\connections strings for your database to do whatever in the DB and could possibly test your scripts.